# Brute force proection practices password reset

Tags: php, mysql, brute-force, forgot-password

I am using php+mysql password reset system based on the folowing steps:

- insert email form
- generate unique hash
- read hash page and authorize reset
- choose new password

Which steps are best to be protected for brute force attack?
My logic tells me that I should protect both email form and the code page that reads the unique hash.
The reason for implementing this on the email form would be to protect somebody from repeatedly using the form for a address he knows it is in the system - i think this is pretty logic but my question is mainly for the code reader page.
Should i limit that page based on ip, session or even total attempts from anywhere in a short time span?
What are the best practices, any documentation on this available?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : This might not be best answer but this is what i practically implemented.

**consider what a hacker can do to beach ?**

1) he will repeatedly sent string of username and password.

2) If his ip get blocked for more input (just like ur phone do if u enter wrong password for more than 5 times). He will relaunch attack after his blocking time.

3)If his IP gets block he will change  his IP virtually and relaunch attack.

=======================================================

**What we (even systems like google/steam) do ?**

1) They keep option for double authentication.

->Like OTP systems for banks. this will make it harder for hacker to hack. as he must require ur OTP on your mobile too which is dynamic.

> 2) Blocking IP will serve purpose : 
>   We can [change  ip in](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/IP-spoofing) few seconds and try to access site again.

3) Blocking account.

-> if a user input  wrong password  for many tries (say 15) you can directly block his account until he himself authenticate it (by he otp sent to his mobile/email).

**Bonus points :**

Formore security

1) Device  detection :

most of users use **specific** device for logging in office computer,thier mobile , home desktop. If you get an input over unfamiliar device send user a notification about it.

2) Detecting invalid requests from a geographic position :

some hackers spoof ip and geographic location but they might forget to change it after unsuccessful attempt and you can use this to learn about attack more and even use a geographic location lock.

Comment: My main question is: do hackers attempt to brute force a validation page like this?
www.mywebsite/validationcode/kjhiaf87rf87tefte84f34f8gf77